# I am unable to call jsp text response through ajax, both files are in same folder. it shows status as error

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

Call to JSP which failed:

```
$.ajax({
                            url:'controlleer.jsp',
                            type:"Get",
                            datatype: "text",
                            success:function(){
                                    console.log("success");
                                },
                            }).always(function(xhr,status){
                                console.log(status);
                            });
```

Response - expected:

controlleer.jsp:

```
 response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.getWriter().write("done");
```

Comment: Provide the full path to the controlleer.jsp including contextPath in url.

Comment: What is the error you get? Can you tell me which page you are at when you do this request and can you tell me which is the path of the target file compared to the URL?

Comment: @LajosArpad xhr status is 0. I have hosted a html web page on my localhost. in web page i have a login modal. onclick of submit i have called an ajax. Controlleer.jsp which is in same folder as of home.html